# Self build executable can only be executed via context menu "run as a program"

Tags: python, python3, .desktop, executable

I am using Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS

I have created an executable using pyinstaller and copied it to the desktop. The problem is that it does not open when double-clicked.

However, if you open the desktop as a folder, it will double-click and run.

Also, right-clicking it on the desktop and selecting "run as program" works. Is there a way to make it run when double-clicked on the desktop?

`ll` returns the following:

```
-rwxr-xr-x  1 mygroup myuser 239950848 Jul  3 15:42 test*
```

Comment: As far as I remember, GNOME removed the possibility of running executables by double-clicking directly on the desktop. You need a launcher (.desktop file) to run anything from the desktop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, try running it from the command line. I guess that will work. Then try adding a .desktop file to your desktop to start it. See https://github.com/shundhammer/qdirstat/blob/master/src/qdirstat.desktop for an example.

Comment: Yes the .desktop file was the solution for my problem. Thanks